# How to query SQL to RichEditControl DevExpress?

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, devexpress

I want to fill data from SQL Server to `RichEditControl.Text`. I used this code but it doesn't work, my `RichEditControl.Text` has an empty string.

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=ADMIN;Initial Catalog=Shoplacviet;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
conn.Open();
string query = "select * from so";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
richEditControl1.Options.MailMerge.DataSource = dt;
richEditControl1.Options.MailMerge.ViewMergedData = true;
richEditControl1.Text = dt.ToString();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What .Net? UI Framework do you use, is it `winforms`, `wpf`, or something else?

Comment: i used winform,  .net 4.8

Comment: You're converting DataTable to string. This doesn't give you the contents of the table. You need to access the appriapriate column(s) and add it to text in your control.

Comment: I try: var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // get the results of each column
                richEditControl1.Text = (string)rdr["noidungso"];
            }  it only show the last row